# Meteor: accessing javascript object element within array element

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I log the following data structure I get the output below:

```
console.log(businessDetails[8])

[ 
  { businessDetails: 
       { companyName: 'Companyname' },
    _id: 'LrqSm5LJcxpo5wW7W' 
  } 
]
```

How can I access the `companyName` field?

I would've thought that I could do it like this:

```
console.log(businessDetails[8].businessDetails.companyName)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

What do I need to do to access this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe: `console.log(businessDetails[8][0].businessDetails.companyName)`

Comment: That worked, the problem I've got is that it doesn't work in a loop so I'll need to try something else.  After the loop runs this code works fine.